# How do I ensure a POST request for a WordPress plugin is made by an admin?

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I ensure that data to be stored for a plugin (let's say it's a setting), is actually made by an admin and not just a random user of the site?

Is this sufficient? (Checking if the user can manage options?)

Or is there a better way to check whether the person is an admin who would be using the plugin?

For example:

```
function myFunction()
{
  if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
    wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
  }
  if(!empty($_POST['pluginSetting']))
  {
     update_option( $option, $_POST['pluginSetting']);
  }
}
```

Comment: There is another way, which in my opinion is clearer. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131814/if-the-current-user-is-an-administrator-or-editor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method of checking the user capability (`current_user_can( 'manage_options' )`) is adequate, since "manage_options" is a capability that only Admins and Super Admins have (unless you customize roles).

To make it a little tighter, I might be inclined to change the logic to specifically check for a "false" boolean.  That way, you are implicitly checking the actual return value from `current_user_can()` is actually false:

```
if ( false === current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) { //...
```

That should help prevent something slipping past your logic.

One other thing you could do to harden beyond that is to use a nonce. You would include a nonce in your form (where the option is being set and submitted/saved) and then validate that nonce before saving the setting.  See: https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces